# Docusign integration salesforce problem

Tags: docusign

When I click **Docusign Admin** tab in my Salesforce Org. this error pops up.

> Error retrieving DocuSign Console information. Please contact your
>   system administrator for access. Error: The UserID did not identify a
>   User in the system.

Need help.

Comment: Did you contact your admin? Most likely you have not been activated as a user for the app

Comment: when i try to type my salesforce org credential in "Connect DocuSign to Salesforce". it show invalid login.

Comment: About all we can do is tell you to make sure your credentials are correct. Suggest you speak with your admin or connect with docusign support.